# Behavior of thread that "finished" on it's own?

Tags: python, multithreading

If the thread target finishes executing (`__do_loop__` set to True), does the thread object delete itself? Can I run the `start_event_loop` again without any problems?

I want to use this behavior in a WxPython program, which [refuses to terminate when an object contains a running thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10833163/how-to-kill-a-wxpython-application-when-user-clicks-a-frames-close).

```
def event_loop(self):
    while self.__do_loop__ == True:
        ...stuff

def start_event_loop(self):
    self.__do_loop__ = True
    self.__thread__ = Thread(target = self.event_loop, args=())
    self.__thread__.start()
```

Comment: You shouldn't be using `__xyz__` for your variables/methods! Use `_xyz` instead.

Comment: settings the daemon attribute to True will allow your wx app to close without any issues

Answer (score 1):

You must still call `join` on the thread object, unless it's in daemon mode.